# iOS CBPeripheral connect Questions

Tags: ios, cbperipheral, bluetooth-lowenergy

I call method

(`void)connectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral options:(nullable NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options;`

to connect my device ,my device is in range , but my app still can't connect my device success, when I turn off system BT and then turn on BT ,my app will connect my device  success , I don't know why ?

If I do not turn off BT and then turn on , May I call first call method

```
(void)cancelPeripheralConnection:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral;
```

then call

(`void)connectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral options:(nullable NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options;`

is it will be make sense ?

Comment: Better call: - connectPeripheral:options:
- cancelPeripheralConnection:

Answer (score 1):

To check weather ***your device is connected or not***, you can user these two delegate methods:
**Objective C:**

**1) -(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral**

**2) -(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CBPeripheral *heartRatePeripheral;
#define heartRateServiceCBUUID [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0x180D"]

-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral 
  *)peripheral
{ 
  [self.Customdelegate HRMoniterStatus:peripheral Status:@"Connected"];
  [_heartRatePeripheral discoverServices:@[heartRateServiceCBUUID]];
}
```

**CustomDelegate:**

```
-(void)HRMoniterStatus:(CBPeripheral *)HRMoniter Status:(NSString 
*)connectionStatus
{
  NSLog(@"HRMoniter connection status ::- %@",connectionStatus);
}
```

---

**Swift :**

**1)  func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral)**

**2) func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?)**

```
let heartRateServiceCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "0x180D")

let heartRatePeripheral : CBPeripheral

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral)
{
    Customdelegate.hrMoniterStatus(peripheral, status: "Connected")
    heartRatePeripheral.discoverServices([heartRateServiceCBUUID])
}
```

**Custom Delegate:**

```
func hrMoniterStatus(_ HRMoniter: CBPeripheral?, status connectionStatus: String?) 
{
   print("HRMoniter connection status ::- \(connectionStatus ?? "")")
}
```